# issue with getLastRow in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a code to transfer copied data from one sheet to another in google sheets. Unfortunately, I'm having issues since the other sheet where I paste the other values has a formula on some column. instead of being set on the next possible available row, "A2" it goes down to "A152"

Here's the code that I am currently using:

```
function submit() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
var mastersheet = ss.getSheetByName("Dump");

var values = [[formSS.getRange("F10").getValue(),
formSS.getRange("C7"),getValue(),
formSS.getRange("C8"),getValue(),]];

mastersheet.getRange(matersheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,3).setValues(values)
}
```

your help will be appreciated!

Comment: I would either write a function to determine the next empty row based on your custom conditions, or if possible, include the formula when you're writing the values. If you choose the latter approach, then you can use the [`appendRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) method: `masterSheet.appendRow([F10, C7, C8, "=1+2"])`

Comment: Thank you, Diego! let me try that method

Answer (score 0):

In order for your code to work, you should use this:

```
function submit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
  var mastersheet = ss.getSheetByName("Dump");
  var values = [formSS.getRange("F10").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("C7").getValue(),
                formSS.getRange("C8").getValue()];

  mastersheet.appendRow(values);
}
```

You should be using the `.appendRow()` method but you don't need to pass the list as a two-dimensional array. Also there were some typos that I fixed in the code snippet you provided.

Furthermore, you can check this link for more information:

- [Append Row Method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents).